# When can Moq throw System.ArgumentException for Object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, interface, moq

I was wondering when can Moq.Object throw System.ArgumentException? The reason I ask that is because for some reason, mocking one of my interfaces throws that exception:

`var exchangeRateService = new Mock<IExchangeRateService>();`

however, interface below this one works fine:

`var hubOwnerRulesServiceMock = new Mock<IHubOwnerRulesService>();`

When I looked at both interfaces, they don't have any differences that I can see that could cause this exception?

Does anyone have any idea for this behaviour and how does one fix it?

**FOUND THE PROBLEM**

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, ExchangeRateDetail>> GetExchangeRates(ICollection<int> setExchangeRateIDs, bool onlyActiveCurrency = false, TecajVrstaEnum? exchangeRateKind = TecajVrstaEnum.Osnovni);
```

The reason I got this exception is because I use optional Enum and Moq can't handle it properly so it throws this exception.

My program example:

```
using Moq;

[TestClass]
public class TestInterCompany
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void Test()
   {
      ...
      var exchangeRateService = new Mock<IExchangeRateService>();
      ...
   }
}
```

**How I fixed it**

I created a new service called

> ExchangeRateServiceUnitTest

which will also implement IExchangeRateService, but instead of mocking IExchangeRateService, I will create object for ExchangeRateServiceUnitTest.

```
public class ExchangeRateServiceUnitTest : IExchangeRateService

public Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, ExchangeRateDetail>> GetExchangeRates(ICollection<int> setExchangeRateIDs, bool onlyActiveCurrency = false, TecajVrstaEnum? exchangeRateKind = TecajVrstaEnum.Osnovni)
{
    return ...
}
```

In this method, I am not going into DB, but rather returning hard coded values since this is just for testing purposes.

Now my unit test looks like this:

```
using Moq;

[TestClass]
public class TestInterCompany
{
   [TestMethod]
   public void Test()
   {
      ...
      var repository = new Mock<Repository>();
      var exchangeRateService = new ExchangeRateServiceUnitTest();
      var interCompanyMappingService = new 
   InterCompanyMappingService(repository.Object, exchangeRateService);
   }
}
```

Since we aren't using .Object, it will not throw exception and it works as we want it to.

Comment: What is the actual message of the exception?

Comment: Doesn't the exception message include a description? If so, what does it say? Is there an InnerException?

Comment: Also, maybe you can look at your interfaces, but we can't, so it's a hard guess for us to help solve your issue. I recommend trying to build a [mcve].

Comment: @MatthewWatson the full message is this:

Object (Moq.Mock) --> '((Moq.Mock)exchangeRateService).Object' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'

Comment: Also, additionaly, when I write:

var interCompanyMappingService = new InterCompanyMappingService(repository, exchangeRateService.Object), it breaks on the Object one with exception:

{"Constant does not match the defined type."}

With inner exception being null.

Comment: Please show use the code of your interfaces.

Comment: @Pac0 I have edited question with both interfaces

Comment: glad you found your solution to the problem! I'd recommend 1) editing the question to show the interfaces or a [mcve] that exhibits the problem and 2) posting an answer to your own question, as it may help other readers who have the same issue.

Comment: @Pac0 alright, I have edited my program with a very basic example of how I use my final solution.

Comment: The accepted way to answer your own question on Stack OVerflow is to actually write an answer and mark it as "accepted". Thus, question will appear as solved for future reader. See for instance [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and [this post on meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)